# Checking the Value of a Specific Column in Every Row of a CSV with Python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

Using data as follows for simplicity:

```
Name,Age,Height
Joe,14,65
Sam,18,74
Sarah,21,62
```

I want to go through each line of the file, compare the `Age` column to some value (for example: 16). If the value is less than the fixed value, I want to delete the line.

In this example, I'd be left with the following data:

```
Name,Age,Height
Sam,18,74
Sarah,21,62
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a basic example, using the csv module. It creates a new file less the criteria data.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv

infile = 'input.csv'
outfile = 'output.csv'

wfh = open(outfile, 'w')

with open(infile, 'r') as fh:

    reader = csv.DictReader(fh, delimiter=',')

    for row in reader:
        name = row['Name']
        age = row['Age']
        height = row['Height']

        if age >= 16:
            wfh.write("{},{},{}".format(name, age, height))

wfh.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f = open('myfile.csv', 'r')
g = open('mynewfile.csv','w')

for line in f:
  if int(line.split(",")[1]) != FIXED_VALUE:
    g.write(line)

f.close()
g.close()
```

for such a simple use-case I wouldn't use external csv libs.

*the code was not tested

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open("file.csv","r")

    lines=f.readlines()

f.close()

    f = open("file.csv","w")

for line in lines:
   if int(line.split(",")[1]) >= 16:
        f.write(line)
f.close()
```